# Using for loop with randint

Tags: python

Using this code:

```
from random import randint
ans = [[randint(0, 20),randint(0, 20),randint(0, 20),randint(0, 20),randint(0, 20),randint(0, 20),randint(0, 20)] for i in range(15)]
print (ans)
```

I got this:

```
[[10, 10, 13, 3, 13, 17, 3], [4, 1, 0, 15, 3, 9, 12], [8, 14, 8, 14, 2, 1, 11], [6, 13, 8, 9, 16, 18, 18], [10, 2, 15, 18, 16, 5, 4], [16, 3, 16, 9, 8, 20, 9], [1, 8, 16, 4, 7, 17, 20], [5, 0, 3, 11, 11, 3, 5], [17, 5, 14, 7, 20, 17, 17], [7, 4, 9, 17, 13, 0, 11], [3, 12, 6, 20, 9, 0, 3], [9, 12, 14, 16, 11, 4, 4], [12, 19, 12, 12, 11, 16, 12], [13, 15, 2, 3, 9, 17, 11], [14, 6, 10, 18, 8, 6, 6]]
```

But as you can see the repetition of `randint(0,20)` isn't good. Could you help me using something else, like a for loop, instead of repeating the same `randint(0,20)`?

Comment: Why not another list comprehension?

Comment: Could you explain what you are looking for and what the problem is?

Comment: Have you considered using NumPy? If you want a two-dimensional list, you may prefer a two-dimensional NumPy array. And NumPy's has built-in functions for generation such random arrays.

Comment: You can see if I want a list of 20 elements I would have to repeat randint(0,20) twenty time, I just simply want to avoid this...

Comment: my teacher doesn't want me to use NumPy's :/

Answer (score 1):

you could do a double list comprehension

```
from random import randint
ans = [[randint(0, 20) for j in range(7)] for i in range(15)]
print (ans)
```

Comment: exactly what i wanted.